# What is the right way to map an object to database

Tags: java, hibernate

i have the object below represented by this JSON:

```
"page":{

"pageId":"123123",
"pageUrl":"www.page.com",
"pageCode":"13123128098e"

"news":{
    "header":{
       "headerId":4413123,
       "headerRef":"On-line",
       "headerName":"On-line Ref.",
    },
    "writerList":[
       {
          "writerId":1,
          "writerName":"Mega Thunder"

       },
       {
          "writerId":2,
          "writerName":"Rain Forest"
       }           
    ]
```

The Java object is an news object that contains an header and an writeList. Right here ok.

But, my doubt is.. when a i map this using hibernate, I'm thinking about if is necessary to have the news object mapped to be an table, because the news object will have only  one id, a reference to header and the writeList object will have one reference to news. Is the news object really necessary to exists on database? can i create only the header and writerList linked to page?

Comment: Look into Jackson or Jersey. You will need to map out your JSON to POJO then your POJO to Hibernate

Comment: So the answer is yes, i really need this object, right?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the following:
`Page`, `News`, `Header`, `ArrayList<WriterList>`.
The rest will be strings or integers. Make sure you `public static class` your inner classes.

Comment: You wouldn't be annotating your JSON pojo with hibernate entities